# How would you typeset the following

Tags: formatting, lists, indentation

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\newenvironment*{exercise}{}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}{1.10.}
Show that $B=\{[a,b)\subset\R|a<b\}$ is a basis for a topology on $\R$.\\
\begin{enumerate}
\item{stuff...}
\item{stuff...}
\end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

My main concern is that the list numbers in the list and the text in the instructions line up. That is that the S in show is lined up with the 1 and 2 etc in the list.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is unclear what you are asking here. Please provide a minimal working example that shows how your document is structured. Then please give a concise question about what you want to achieve. You may have a look at the `enumitem` package that can be used to customise lists.

Comment: welcome to tex.se! how id determined "1.10 Determine the following..." is this part of` enumerate` list or it is determined as `subsection` or ...? please show us what you try so far, the best in form of complete but small document beginning with `\documentclass...` and ending by `\end{document}`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for providing an MWE! Using the package `enumitem` may be a solution for you:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{exercise}[1]{\noindent\makebox[10mm][l]{#1}\ignorespaces}{}

\newlist{steps}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[steps]{itemindent=10mm,label=\alph*),align=left}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}{1.10.}
Show that $B=\{[a,b)\subset\R|a<b\}$ is a basis for a topology on $\R$.
  \begin{steps}
    \item{stuff...}
    \item{stuff...}
  \end{steps}
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the function of the parameter 5 in the definition of your newlist?

Comment: @ChristianHarris It is the maximum depth: this means you can put a `steps` environment inside another `steps` environment and go five levels deep this way. If your exercises don't have substeps you may as well use `1` here, and if they do you'll probably want to customise the `<n>`-th level separately with `\setlist[steps,<n>]{...}`. See the `enumitem` documentation [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) for more information.